# How to create ad on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to boost a post on my Facebook page. All goes well but once putting debit card information on payment window, it gives error to provide correct security code or expiration date, where it should not be giving this error because same credentials are working fine on other websites.

I am looking for help, how would be able to connect to Facebook support for this particular issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an actual programming question. For Facebook end user support, consult their Help section.

Comment: @04FS, you're right this is off-topic, but don't recommend the facebook help center, because it doesn't work. There is effectively ZERO support there. What they write in their help articles and what their web application does are basically unrelated.

Comment: @AltimusPrime I know Facebook does not give real end user support (probably due to size of user base), but the Help section allows people to ask questions in there, and get them answered by the “community”. Plus they have a reporting form in there to let them know if “something is not working”. I don’t think anyone here can do anything more for OP.

Comment: For an SO forum, maybe it should be migrated to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/